# WebEngine is not loading files linked in HTML (javafx)

Tags: java, html, webview, javafx-8

Here is the `<head>` tag of *content.html*:

```
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="matchbrackets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="closebrackets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="expression.js"></script>
    <style>
        .right {
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

File is loaded via:

```
view.getEngine().load(getClass().getResource("content.html").toExternalForm());
```

HTML file loads just fine, but none of the files referenced with **src** or **href** (css/js). All linked files are in the same package as HTML file. So is the class that loads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just tried to compile it with old 1.8_45 JDK and it works as intended, so it seems like some major fault on Orracle's side.

**Update:**

Bug fixed in Java 8u72 !