# including javascript to javafx webview

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx, webview

i'm trying to make simple webview based on local file html and js. I don't know why, but my app.js is not loading. Same code that is there works when it's  element.

I have image in the same folder and it works without problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<img src="img.jpg">
```

I'm begginer to javafx, so i don't even know where to find help.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429069/loading-local-javascript-file-in-webview-in-java-8u60

Comment: This should not be an issue anymore, if the OP is using up-to-date JDK/JRE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280069/webengine-is-not-loading-files-linked-in-html-javafx/32320309#32320309

Comment: My java is 8u91, so i guess it's not version issue

Comment: I can confirm the file linking works in 8u91, so the problem is elsewhere. PS: check that both JDK & JRE are up-to-date, JDK does not update automatically & IDEs use it when debugging.

Comment: "No base JDK. Package will use system JRE." I found this error in command line and i don't know what to do about that...